# Mysql - Update only 1 row from same records

Tags: mysql

I need to update row which having same value in debit column & only row which having create_date ASC basically 2019-11-15

I am having transaction table with following data

```
table name - tbl_transactions

id     client_id     user_id    debit    add_date
1      9991101       1          7.69     2019-11-15
2      9991101       1          7.69     2019-11-30
3      9991101       2          28.9     2019-11-15
4      9991101       2          11.49    2019-11-30
```

Now i just want to UPDATE record which have same value in column "debit" & date "2019-11-15"

**which means only id-1 will be get updated.**

```
 id     client_id     user_id    debit    add_date
 1      999110100     1          7.69     2019-11-15
```

We can add additional 00 to client_id field, i have tried with below sql but seems its not working

```
UPDATE tbl_transactions 
SET    client_id=999110100 
WHERE  id IN ( 
          SELECT   * 
          FROM     tbl_transactions 
          WHERE    client_id=9991101 
          AND      DATE(create_date)='2019-11-15' 
          GROUP BY user_id, debit HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to describe which field need to update, what to set in new value etc. And you should try something first.

Comment: @STEVE001 , What is your MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, you can try a query like

```
UPDATE
  `tbl_transactions`
SET
  `COLUMN_NAME` = DESIRED_VALUE
WHERE
  `debit` = 7.69
AND
  `add_date` = '2019-11-15'
```

You just need to replace COLUMN_NAME in the above query with your desired column name and it's respective value ahead of it. Do let me know if that's what you're trying to achieve or something else.

Answer (score 0):

> Mysql cannot specify target table for update in FROM clause.

You need to use **subquery** select them in a temporary table and update it,

And you can use **CONCAT** to concat your client_id with `00`,

According to your post, you need the same debit and order by created_date ASC,

however, **mysql cannot just order a field in group**, so you can do it like this:

```sql
UPDATE
  `tbl_transactions`
SET
  `client_id` = CONCAT(client_id, '00')
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT t2.id, t2.user_id t2.created_date FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, user_id, MIN(created_date) AS created_date
        FROM tbl_transactions
        WHERE client_id=9991101
        GROUP BY user_id, debit 
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
    ) AS t1
    INNER JOIN tbl_transactions AS t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.debit = t2.debit AND t2.client_id = 9991101 AND t1.created_date = t2.created_date
    GROUP BY t2.user_id
  ) AS temp_table 
)
```

Comment: do u means `SELECT id 
    FROM tbl_transactions 
    WHERE client_id=9991101 AND DATE(create_date)='2019-11-15' 
    GROUP BY user_id, debit 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2` this sql not returning result?

Comment: Yes I tried below sql

SELECT id FROM tbl_transactions WHERE client_id=9991101 AND DATE(create_date)='2019-11-15' GROUP BY user_id, debit HAVING COUNT(*) > 1